# How can you join a dbContext to another one only on some specific conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

I'm trying to join two tables without any relationship.
Here's the simplified version of what I try to reach.

First table has these values:

| Address | SomeOtherID |
| --- | --- |
| XYZ | NULL |
| ABC | 3 |
| DEF | NULL |
| GHI | 2 |

The other table has these values:

ID NAME
1  Alice
2  ...
3  ...

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice |
| 2 | Bob |
| 3 | Cedric |
| 4 | Diana |

I need to join these two so I obtain something like this:

ID NAME  Address SomeOtherID
1  Alice NULL    NULL
2  Bob   GHI     2

| ID | NAME | Address | SomeOtherID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alice | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | Bob | GHI | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

For the moment I have this:

```
var candidates = dbContext.Candidate.Include(x => x.CandidateClass.Eassessment.EassessmentTranslations)
                    .Join(_dbContext.CandidateExternalInvoiceAdress, x => x.CandidateExternalInvoiceId, y=> y.Id, (cdte, cdteEIA) => new { cdte, cdteEIA })
```

This gives me only when the two numbers match, but `x.CandidateExternalInvoiceId` is an `int?` and `y.Id` is an `int`. I want in the case that the first Id is null, then it joins a null object of `cdteEIA`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: @NicholasHunter I tried a workaround but this seems that it can do the job